# Using getInitialProps with an optional Parameter with NextJS

Tags: next.js

I have a page which allows a user to update a record, lets call it /edit-record, I want to support /edit-record/1 as a route which would load the data (I tried using getInitialProps) but I also want to make it so /edit-record is a page (ideally the same page) but without the API call to fetch the details happening.

So if I pass /edit-record/3 it should fetch record 3, if the url is /edit-record it just awaits user events.

The issue being I tried a conditional in getInitialProps, a if(query.recordId) {} but the else clause returns a null which NextJS doesnt like; it also just feels a bit wrong in terms of the approach.

What is the better way? Ideally I don't want to create two page files to handle the two conditions as all of the logic is the same.

Comment: What does "awaits user calls" mean? How are the logic for the two kinds of pages here the same? Why not make `/edit-record/index.js` and `/edit-record/[id].js`? If you are worried about duplicated logic, extract it into a function.

Comment: Pretty sure that approach is not optimal (or close), NextJS has support for optional Params using [[...id]].jsx so there must be some provision for that in getInitialProps.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried? Using a page like `edit-record/[[...id]].jsx` should work for your use case.